# Video thumbnails are duplicated for multiple videos in a grid

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html5-video, gatsby

#### Background

Creating a portfolio page showcasing images and videos using Gatsby/React. I have stored the media sources in an array and then I traverse over this array to create a grid.

#### Problem

The video thumbnails in the grid are getting duplicated. The second video is getting the thumbnail of first video:
[image]

Although, the dev tools show different sources for these videos.
[image]

Happens again on another page:
[image]

Video objects are created as following:

```
<VideoContainer key={`vid-${section}-${itemCounter}`}>
  <video className="proj-video" preload="metadata">
    <source src={currImg.src} type={`videomp4`} />
  </video>
  <div className="btn-container">
    <FontAwesomeIcon color="white" size="4x" icon="play" />
  </div>
</VideoContainer>
```

`<VideoContainer />` is a styled div.

It happens on multiple videos. What I've tried so far:

1. Ensure that the sources of these videos are different. When the video is played (by clicking on the play button over the thumbnail), correct video is played.
2. Add a `key` attribute on the `video` tag as well. But, it doesn't solves the problem.

**Note:** It is very indeterministic behavior because it doesn't happens always. Sometime, it gets corrected on page refresh and sometimes it doesn't.

#### Edit

You can see that I am not setting thumbnail from another source. It just displays the video frame. I append `"#t=10"` (any number) at the end of video URL and add `preload="metadata"` on the video tag to load the frame at that time.

Comment: This sounds like it could be a rehydration failure. Make sure you're not doing anything that would result in your initial client-side render producing markup that doesn't match your static, server-side rendered markup.

Comment: @coreyward I'll look into it. I don't know about the hydration problems so I'll study about it and update later. Thanks.

Comment: @coreyward I did some research and I can imagine it being a rehydration failure. But, I couldn't trace it in the code (no such code causing different server-side rendering). Also, I don't get any such [warning](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/the-perils-of-rehydration/#about-gatsby-in-particular) in my development mode. Although, changing the key as said in the answer below has solved the issue, I don't think that was the problem (again, no warnings for duplicate keys). Can you say anything about this?

Comment: I know it will be difficult to say anything without looking at the code. Unfortunately, I can't share the code. If any common problems come to your mind from your experience, do let me know! Thanks, again :)

Comment: Gatsby won't show warnings for hydration mismatches because it renders client-side in development and it doesn't support using the development mode of React for builds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a more unique key:

```
<VideoContainer key={currImg}>
  <video className="proj-video" preload="metadata">
    <source src={currImg.src} type={`videomp4`} />
  </video>
  <div className="btn-container">
    <FontAwesomeIcon color="white" size="4x" icon="play" />
  </div>
</VideoContainer>
```

`vid-${section}-${itemCounter}`, for its own nature, is a good identifier but not a good `key`, but it seems that may not be as unique as `currImg` is.

Comment: Wow. It seems to have solved the problem! But, as I said it happens sometimes, so I'll take some time to ensure that it works. By the way, can you please explain this solution? I never get duplicate key warning for what I was using. I also use the same pattern `img-${section}-${itemCounter}` for images in my grid and it doesn't cause any problems there. So, why is it so?

Comment: Sure! `key` is used by React to know what elements are updated, deleted, etc. So the should be a unique `id`. Despite React doesn't warn you (because the `key` was there), the way that was built warned me that it may be duplicated or wrong, it usually happens when dealing with indexes of the loops, because it's something that's not unique for that loop and may be repeated somewhere else.

Comment: @FerranBuireu Keys only have to be unique amongst their siblings though. You only really get into trouble when you replace an array of one type with an array of another type, but have overlapping keys between them, but this is pretty rare.